# Мне нужно добавлять новых пользователей беседы телеграм в массив в самом файле бота

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Всем здравствуйте!
Я пишу развлекательного чат-бота на библиотеке PyTelegramBotApi, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы id новых пользователей добавлялись в массив. По команде, из этого массива рандомно берётся 2 айдишника пользователей  группы и выводится в сообщение, это я сам сделаю. Функционал похаж на https://t.me/iris_cm_bot при команда (шипперим), этим я и вдохновился. Прошу помочь

Comment: Лучше уж сохраняйте массив в json, а еще лучше в базу данных :)

Comment: это да, но мне легче будет доставать именно из массива

Comment: Это и будет массив, но в json, а ваша идея модификации списка в самом файле это костыль :)